# NLP - Separate punctuations only at the start and end of the words

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I'm new at NLP and I'm trying basic preprocessing steps while learning. I'm trying to separate punctuations at the start and end of words for embeddings. While doing that, I don't want to damage words like `can't`, `I'm`, etc. because I'm handling them separately.

```
s = 'This is what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure out how.'
```

Desired output:

```
s_separated = 'This is what I'm trying to do , but I can't figure out how .'
```

Comment: Can you please include your current approach and where it fails

Comment: the regex for word boundaries is `\b` so something like `r',\b'` will find commas at the end of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
import re

str = "This is what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure out how."
res = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)(?=[,.!;:])', ' ', str)
print res
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/afaNXm/1)